# org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find play-services-basement.aar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, jcenter

I am using `15.0.1` version of Firebase and Google Play Services. The build has started breaking today. How do I fix this? Following is the Gradle logs for reference.

```
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred configuring project ':demo'.
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  Run with --scan to get full insights.
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':demo'.
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:89)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:70)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:34)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:110)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:667)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:136)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:261)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:173)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:132)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:115)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:62)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:86)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 82 more
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler.computeResourceSetList0(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:151)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler.getResDirectories(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:110)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler.getResDirectories(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:18)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin$applyExperimental$4.invoke(AndroidSubplugin.kt:196)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin$applyExperimental$4.invoke(AndroidSubplugin.kt:75)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler$sam$org_gradle_api_Action$0.execute(Android25ProjectHandler.kt)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:136)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler.forEachVariant(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:24)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin.applyExperimental(AndroidSubplugin.kt:194)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin.apply(AndroidSubplugin.kt:101)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin.apply(AndroidSubplugin.kt:75)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.SubpluginEnvironment.addSubpluginOptions(KotlinPlugin.kt:816)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler.processVariant(KotlinPlugin.kt:636)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler.access$processVariant(KotlinPlugin.kt:496)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler$handleProject$2$1.invoke(KotlinPlugin.kt:556)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler$handleProject$2$1.invoke(KotlinPlugin.kt:496)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler$sam$org_gradle_api_Action$0.execute(Android25ProjectHandler.kt)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:136)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler.forEachVariant(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:24)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler$handleProject$2.execute(KotlinPlugin.kt:555)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler$handleProject$2.execute(KotlinPlugin.kt:496)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 89 more
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':demo:qaDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:944)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1600(DefaultConfiguration.java:120)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.ensureResolved(DefaultConfiguration.java:1285)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.getArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:1257)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.computeResourceSetList(MergeResources.java:723)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 116 more
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1).
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Searched in the following locations:
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/15.0.1/play-services-basement-15.0.1.aar
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.resolve.result.DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.notFound(DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.java:27)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(ExternalResourceResolver.java:434)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:427)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:181)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.java:80)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$ArtifactResolverChain.resolveArtifact(ComponentResolversChain.java:121)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(ErrorHandlingArtifactResolver.java:46)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.DefaultArtifactSet$LazyArtifactSource.create(DefaultArtifactSet.java:170)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.DefaultArtifactSet$LazyArtifactSource.create(DefaultArtifactSet.java:157)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultResolvedArtifact.getFile(DefaultResolvedArtifact.java:135)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ArtifactBackedResolvedVariant$DownloadArtifactFile.run(ArtifactBackedResolvedVariant.java:148)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.access$900(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$ParentPreservingQueueWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:378)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runOperation(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:230)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.access$600(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:172)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable$1.call(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:209)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable$1.call(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:203)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runBatch(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:202)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.run(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:177)
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 3 more
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 55s
```

Comment: the error says: Run with --scan to get full insights. did you try that?

Comment: also without any code its hard to guess what went wrong check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944600/4255978

Comment: There is nothing in the repo https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-bintray/com/google/android/gms/. Seems like all the artifacts have been removed.

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944600/4255978

Comment: visit this , hope this is your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/75005827/12748481

Answer (score 16):

I've had the same issue. For whatever reason the play-services-basement library is no longer available in **jcenter**: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/15.0.1/play-services-basement-15.0.1.aar

In the **google** repository the version 15.0.1 is still available though. You can search the lib here: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html

You probably receive the error because you've declared the jcenter() repository before the google() repository. In case a library cannot be resolved in the repository specified first, the build fails with something like this:

```
> Could not find play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/15.0.1/play-services-basement-15.0.1.aar
```

Make sure that you declare the google() repository before jcenter() in your `build.gradle` file and it should work again:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Downgrading the Gradle version along with the above-mentioned change fixed it for me.

Comment: If this fails, try rebuilding after deleting the .gradle package. This helped me fix this.

Comment: Just keeping google() above jcenter() fixed my issue.. Thanks

Comment: Worked for  me as well

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue I downgraded from `3.2.0` to `3.1.4` and also deleted the whole `.gradle` folder.

Comment: From which version to which version you downgraded? I'm experiencing same issue even though I placed google() before jcenter(). My gradle version is 4.10

Comment: @muthuraj Downgraded from "3.2.0" to "3.1.4". Also, delete the .gradle  folder and rebuild.

Comment: Thanks @navneet_kumar , I fixed the issue by upgrading play-services version. Posted detail answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/52982816/3423932

Comment: If it answered your question and fixed your problem it would be nice if you mark my answer as accepted :)

Comment: I downgraded from `3.4.1` to `3.1.4` and also deleted the whole `.gradle` folder. Solved my issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to jcenter. Recently in jcenter, many libraries aar files are removed but the pom files are kept in place.
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/15.0.1/

And for some unknown reasons, whatever order you put your repositories, jcenter is first searched for the libraries. In this case, play-services-basement version in your project is 15.0.1 and the same version is available in jcenter. But the aar file is missing,hence gradle throws error. Workaround (or is it the fix?)is to increase the play-service version to the latest version (16.0.0 or 16.0.1).

Fortunately, jcenter don't have the latest version for this library, so gradle searches jcenter first for 16.x, it is not found, then searches maven and downloads it from there.

After fixing this, I actually had related error again in multidex-instrumentation which version was 1.0.2. I manually included that dependency and changed the version to 1.0.3(latest) and then the error is gone.

So if you get this kind of error again for any dependency, search for the latest version for that dependency, include the dependency with latest version manually in your build.gradle (even if you haven't included that dependency previously).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this when update firebase version in my project