# Facing the issue while gradle sync - Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2)

Tags: java, android, gradle, jcenter

I have updated Android Studio to 3.2.1 and now stoped on point with such issue:
Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar

I have tried to reorder my build.gradle file.
Still, you can find the attachment here.

I have tried all the solutions.

I know this question has duplicates but their solution is not working.
[image]

Comment: could you please share the code instead of a screenshot?

Comment: in my case was a command-line options, take a look into it https://stackoverflow.com/a/59376069/2238515

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were lots of similar issues raised the past days, that could be solved by adding the `google()` repository in first position in the `repositories` block of the build scripts.
See detailed explanation in the following answers:

- [couldn't locate lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar for flutter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945041/couldnt-locate-lint-gradle-api-26-1-2-jar-for-flutter-project)
- [Could not find play-services-basement.aar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563407/could-not-find-play-services-basement-aar/51213879#51213879)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52982816/6899896
- [Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279792/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildaapt23-2-0/50290877#50290877)

The root cause , related to missing libraries in Jcenter, is explained in detail here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50885939/6899896

**Note** see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52947028/6899896 : you need to modify .flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle in addition to your project's build scripts (module & app levels) to set repo google() first and jcenter() last

Answer (score 0):

In case you're actually trying to run a Flutter project, you also need to change the order in the flutter gradle file:

`<flutter directory>/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle`

I also updated gradle to the latest version (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html) and restarted Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**:

1. Open `<flutter_dir>\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle`
2. Replace `buildscript` with this (the order of repositories does matter)

   ```
     buildscript {
       repositories {
         jcenter()
         maven {
           url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
         }
     }
     dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As written in https://flutter.su/note/1, you should find a .gradle-file for your project (in Android it is usually app/build.gradle) and change (an order of repositories makes sense):

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
    }
    ...
}

...

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        google()
    }
}
```