# Flutter fresh project got error with lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, flutter, jcenter

I've just created a new project in Android Studio for Flutter.
Now I get this strange error:

> Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
>   Initializing gradle... Resolving dependencies...
>   * Error running Gradle: Exit code 1 from: C:\Users\bruker\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat
>   app:properties: Project evaluation failed including an error in
>   afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the
>   afterEvaluate {} error.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'C:\Users\bruker\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\app\build.gradle'
>     line: 25
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
>   >     Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 0s
>
> Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the
>   android/ folder.

I read that you should add some maven dependency, but I am not using maven at all. This is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I dont use maven for my project.

.packages file:

```
# Generated by pub on 2018-11-04 18:57:06.695056.
analyzer:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.32.4/lib/
args:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/args-1.5.0/lib/
async:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-2.0.8/lib/
boolean_selector:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/boolean_selector-1.0.4/lib/
charcode:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/charcode-1.1.2/lib/
collection:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/collection-1.14.11/lib/
convert:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/convert-2.0.2/lib/
crypto:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/crypto-2.0.6/lib/
csslib:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/csslib-0.14.5/lib/
cupertino_icons:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.2/lib/
flutter:file:///C:/Users/bruker/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/
flutter_test:file:///C:/Users/bruker/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/
front_end:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/front_end-0.1.4/lib/
glob:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/glob-1.1.7/lib/
html:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/html-0.13.3+3/lib/
http:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.11.3+17/lib/
http_multi_server:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http_multi_server-2.0.5/lib/
http_parser:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http_parser-3.1.3/lib/
io:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/io-0.3.3/lib/
js:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.1+1/lib/
json_rpc_2:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/json_rpc_2-2.0.9/lib/
kernel:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/kernel-0.3.4/lib/
logging:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/logging-0.11.3+2/lib/
matcher:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/matcher-0.12.3+1/lib/
meta:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.1.6/lib/
mime:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mime-0.9.6+2/lib/
multi_server_socket:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/multi_server_socket-1.0.2/lib/
node_preamble:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/node_preamble-1.4.4/lib/
package_config:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/package_config-1.0.5/lib/
package_resolver:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/package_resolver-1.0.4/lib/
path:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path-1.6.2/lib/
plugin:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/plugin-0.2.0+3/lib/
pool:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pool-1.3.6/lib/
pub_semver:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pub_semver-1.4.2/lib/
quiver:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/quiver-2.0.0+1/lib/
shelf:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shelf-0.7.3+3/lib/
shelf_packages_handler:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shelf_packages_handler-1.0.4/lib/
shelf_static:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shelf_static-0.2.8/lib/
shelf_web_socket:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shelf_web_socket-0.2.2+4/lib/
sky_engine:file:///C:/Users/bruker/flutter/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine/lib/
source_map_stack_trace:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/source_map_stack_trace-1.1.5/lib/
source_maps:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/source_maps-0.10.7/lib/
source_span:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/source_span-1.4.1/lib/
stack_trace:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stack_trace-1.9.3/lib/
stream_channel:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stream_channel-1.6.8/lib/
string_scanner:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/string_scanner-1.0.4/lib/
term_glyph:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/term_glyph-1.0.1/lib/
test:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/test-1.3.0/lib/
typed_data:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/typed_data-1.1.6/lib/
utf:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/utf-0.9.0+5/lib/
vector_math:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vector_math-2.0.8/lib/
vm_service_client:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vm_service_client-0.2.6/lib/
watcher:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/watcher-0.9.7+10/lib/
web_socket_channel:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/web_socket_channel-1.0.9/lib/
yaml:file:///C:/Users/bruker/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/yaml-2.1.15/lib/
flutter_app1:lib/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [couldn't locate lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar for flutter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945041/couldnt-locate-lint-gradle-api-26-1-2-jar-for-flutter-project)

Comment: @anmol.majhail I dont use maven for my project, so its not a duplicate.

Comment: in the file: .flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle add google() above jcenter()

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53014070/6899896  . if you google your error message you will find multiple SO issues related  to this problem : https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22Could+not+find+lint-gradle-api.jar%22&oq=%22Could+not+find+lint-gradle-api.jar%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j0.2792j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: the google() on top of jcenter doesn't always work. I would like to see an actual explanation.    is jcenter getting broken? jcenter actually HAS the .pom version but not .jar version.

Comment: Where is the file ".flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"? I dont have it in my project. I have one file named "build.gradle" in the android folder. I also see a file named ".packages".