# Android gradle sync failed: Could not find exifinterface.jar (com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When I perform sync gradle I can see following errors:

18:08:37.929 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not find exifinterface.jar (com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1).
18:08:37.929 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   Searched in the following locations:
18:08:37.929 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/exifinterface/27.1.1/exifinterface-27.1.1.jar

Has anybody face the same? How to fix it?

Comment: there are plenty of similar questions the last past days, see one example here :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52982816/6899896   you need to add `google()` in first position in your `repositories` blocks

Comment: in your case:  see under  https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/exifinterface/27.1.1/   => the `pom.xml` is there , but not the jar... which is causing your error.

Comment: @M.Ricciuti thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: check here for the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51151050/8034839

Comment: better answer can be found here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50885939/6899896  (opended in June...), which explains the root cause with Jcenter issue.