# Flutter is not running?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, android-ndk, flutter

> I have some problems while running flutter in android studio

This is my error
Launching lib\main.dart on Moto C Plus in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
* Error running Gradle:
Exit code 1 from: D:\FlutterPrograms\app\android\gradlew.bat app:properties:
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to E:\Sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\FlutterPrograms\app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 25
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration 'classpath'.
  >   Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

> This is my buid.gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> This is my gradle error

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.shanmukh.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [couldn't locate lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar for flutter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945041/couldnt-locate-lint-gradle-api-26-1-2-jar-for-flutter-project)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945041/couldnt-locate-lint-gradle-api-26-1-2-jar-for-flutter-project

Answer (score 1):

There were lots of similar issues raised the past days, that could be solved by adding the `google()` repository in first position in the `repositories` block of the build scripts.
See detailed explanation in the following answers:

- [couldn't locate lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar for flutter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945041/couldnt-locate-lint-gradle-api-26-1-2-jar-for-flutter-project)
- [Could not find play-services-basement.aar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563407/could-not-find-play-services-basement-aar/51213879#51213879)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52982816/6899896
- [Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279792/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildaapt23-2-0/50290877#50290877)

The root cause , related to missing libraries in Jcenter, is explained in detail here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50885939/6899896

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52947028/6899896 : you need to modify `.flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle` in addition to your project's build scripts (module & app levels) to set repo `google()` first and `jcenter()` last

Comment: I am very sorry  to disturbing you again and again. I am very new to Flutter I was unable to find folder called .flutter      where is .flutter folder and flutter.gradle folder

Comment: This should be the directory where you have installed Flutter

Comment: Thank you reply. I will try it.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much for your reply. you are genius. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Open the root flutter folder in your computer, and open the gradle folder in that root folder (For example C:\flutter\package\flutter_tool\gradle) and add '**google()**' to the buildscript. It fixed the issue for me.

Flutter root folder:

[image]

Add '**google()**' to the buildscript:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution!
Go to your flutter folder. After you need to find flutter.gradle. On my PC:
C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle 
Open flutter.gradle with note or notepad and change 
buildscript from this:

```
 repositories {
   jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
    }    
}
```

to this:

```
 repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
    } 
    jcenter()
}
```