# FLutter - Error trying to run the application

Tags: android, windows, gradle, flutter

First sorry for bad English.
I'm starting in Flutter, I already installed everything that is necessary but when trying to run the test app (either in the emulator or the device) I get the error messages below.

---

Launching lib\main.dart on XT1097 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
Exit code 1 from: C:\Testes\first_app\android\gradlew.bat app:properties:
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Testes\first_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 25
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
  >   Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

**************This is the result of my flutter Doctor**************************

[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.9.4, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.17134.345], locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 0.9.4 at C:\Src\flutter
    • Framework revision f37c235c32 (5 weeks ago), 2018-09-25 17:45:40 -0400
    • Engine revision 74625aed32
    • Dart version 2.1.0-dev.5.0.flutter-a2eb050044

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\AKC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    X Android license status unknown.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 29.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.27.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 2.19.0

[√] Connected devices (1 available)
    • XT1097 • 0011102704 • android-arm • Android 6.0 (API 23)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

---

I've tried to resolve the android licenses running flutter doctor --android-licenses but the error has returned

Thanks, if anyone can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [couldn't locate lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar for flutter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945041/couldnt-locate-lint-gradle-api-26-1-2-jar-for-flutter-project)

Comment: question already asked several times the past few days . see one of the multiple solutions here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53003550/6899896

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, a lot of people is experiencing that both to new and old projects (including me).

It's [already solved](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/23397), but it's not yet in the `beta` channel (which is currently the most stable one).

I suggest you to temporarily switch to the `master` channel (most recent and least stable), later you can switch back to the `beta` channel.

As you're new to flutter, I must say that this is uncommon, it's the first time I see a serious problem like that take more than a week to get solved - and as you can see in the issue in the link, the root cause is NOT flutter itself.

#### list channels and see which one you're using

```
flutter channel
```

#### switch to master and upgrade

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I removed my flutter, and downloaded the master channel version. It worked!
Thank you again!

Comment: I think that's what you done, but just to be sure: you don't need to 'remove' your flutter. Flutter itself already switch between its respective git branches by using the flutter command line tool with the channel option. You're welcome, and good coding.